# What kind of list is this?

Tags: python

Could you have a look at the following:

```
{'2013-01-02': {'Volume': '4202600000', 'Adj Close': '1462.42', 'High': '1462.43', 'Low': '1426.19', 'Close': '1462.42', 'Open': '1426.19'}}
```

What is this? Not a list for sure, bc I cant do:

```
print [0]
```

for instance..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a list, it is a [Python dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). You can use the keys to index:

```
print obj['2013-01-02']
```

or you can loop over the keys:

```
for key in obj:
    print key: obj[key]
```

Each *value* in the dictionary is itself another dictionary.

I recommend you read up on Python dictionaries in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoteed.. Because it is a dictionary. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: @Torxed: Most likely because I dared to answer the question.

Comment: @noob do some research

Comment: @martijn-pieters Yea probably. Kudos for keeping it up with the perfect answers despite this crap tbh. You're a champ on the Python section!

Comment: @noob: That depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks; now that I know what 'it' is, I think I will be able to figure it out myself...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a list, it is a dictionary (key -> value) where the key is the date and the value is a dictionary where the key is a string and the value another string.

so if you wanna know the Volume at 2013-01-02 you can do

```
ris = map['2013-01-02']['Volume']
```

ps. dictionary are often call map in other languages

Comment: Actually, 'maps' are called dictionaries in Python and the other answer is just better, IMO.

Comment: fixed, thanks, i'm not a phyton boy but i recognise a map/dictionarie when i see it :)